# Concatenating strings in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I'd like to have a throttling rule in HAProxy that limits rate at which a user can load any particular path, but I don't know of a way to concatenate strings in HAProxy (at least, in the context of generating a key for a stick table). So what I'd like is

```
tcp-request content track-sc1 concat(req.cook(user), path)
tcp-request content reject if {sc1_http_req_rate gt 10}
```

[HAProxy manipulate string prior to map lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423249/haproxy-manipulate-string-prior-to-map-lookup) suggests using `regsub` to do something somewhat similar, but I think I can only do constant manipulations with that.

The best I've come up with so far is to track `path` and `req.cook(user)` separately, and to reject if each of them is too high, but this isn't the actual behavior that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question has the answer. You concat in set-header first and then use that.

```
http-request set-header X-Concat %[req.cook(user)]__%[path]
http-request track-sc0 hdr(X-Concat) table peruser
```